# One On tap function

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. I try to create an ecomm app. I have a 10 categories and 1 custom widget. How to use on tap function to direct this 10 categories? I mean for each _categoryTap use direct for this categories. Something like this: `_categoryTap(Navigate to)` or ?. Sorry for my bad english)) my code:

```
class ListOfCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListOfCategoryState createState() => _ListOfCategoryState();
}

class _ListOfCategoryState extends State<ListOfCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 40, right: 40),
            child: Image.asset('assets/dafna_logo.png'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


  Widget _categoryTap(String _nameCategory) {

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 120,
              height: 35,
              // color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(_nameCategory,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are doing it in the static way then this is the below sample you can check

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 40, right: 40),
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _categoryTap('test1'),
                  _categoryTap('test2'),
                  _categoryTap('test3'),
                  _categoryTap('test4'),
                  _categoryTap('test5'),
                  _categoryTap('test6'),
                  _categoryTap('test6'),
                  _categoryTap('test8'),
                  _categoryTap('test9'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _categoryTap(String _nameCategory) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print('tap');
        switch (_nameCategory) {
          case 'test1':
            {
              // statements;
              print('Test 1');
            }
            break;

          case 'test2':
            {
              //statements;
            }
            break;
          // .... and so on
          default:
            {
              //statements;
              print('you command whatever you want');
            }
            break;
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 120,
              height: 35,
              // color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                _nameCategory,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

let me know if it works Thanks.

Comment: Instead of putting the switch in the _categoryTap Widget I would put the function somewhere and then have the _categoryTap widget call it, passing in the _nameCategory.

This way there's just the one instance of the function no matter how many _categoryTap instances you make.

Answer (score 0):

try out this :

```
class ListOfCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListOfCategoryState createState() => _ListOfCategoryState();
}

class _ListOfCategoryState extends State<ListOfCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 40, right: 40),
            child: Image.asset('assets/dafna_logo.png'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _categoryTap(String _nameCategory) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        redirectToEditProfile(context);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 120,
              height: 35,
              // color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(_nameCategory,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




void redirectToEditProfile(BuildContext context) async {
  await Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
      opaque: false,
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
        return (Your Redirecting Activity);
      }));

}
```